# How to apply CMA-ES optimization to an arbitrary user defined objective function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, functional-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am new in using Python. These days I am trying to learn new optimization algorithms and python.

CMA-ES optimization algorithm source code in Python can be found here:
[CMA-ES.py](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cma.py)

I have had all the necessary Python packages installed (numpy,matplotlib, winpython, and so on). It is also easy to run the testing functions provided by the source code, e.g.,

```
            >>> import cma
            >>> res = cma.fmin(cma.fcts.rosen, 4*[-1],1, ftarget=1e-6, restarts=3, verb_time=0, verb_disp=500, seed=3)
```

The desired customized objective function is from the nonlinear least square fittiing of data:

Data sets: 23x3

```
x        y      z
----------------------
1100.21 57.66   1.8
1157.88 57.79   1.7
1272.85 58.03   1.67
1330.34 58.22   1.67
1389.   57.69   1.7
1590.   57.01   1.67
1820.   55.42   1.6
2049.   59.35   1.5
2308.   58.32   1.56
2596.   57.28   1.6
2711.   57.13   1.368
2826.   55.61   1.33
2883.   54.79   1.315
2940.   53.78   1.325
3001.   54.41   1.3
3117.   55.93   1.2495
3291.   57.15   1.28
3377.   58.05   1.25
3522.   58.41   1.31
3725.   57.61   1.31
3899.   53.55   1.195
4015.   51.22   1.178
4188.   50.89   1.185
```

nonlinear model : a(1)--a(5) are parameters:

```
 z = a(1)*y^a(2)*x^a(3)+a(4)*x^a(5)
```

Comment: What is the problem then? Have you tried the objective function you want? Does it work? Why not?

Comment: I have no idea how to create the objective function in python and apply CMA algorithm on it

Comment: You wrote you want least square fit of the data: `def obj(a): return ((z-z_hat(a))**2).sum()` where `z_hat = a(1)*y^a(2)*x^a(3)+a(4)*x^a(5)`

Comment: I even have no idea how to handle such a 23x3 array, which I used to manipulate easily via Octave, C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
data = """
1100.21 57.66   1.8
1157.88 57.79   1.7
1272.85 58.03   1.67
1330.34 58.22   1.67
1389.   57.69   1.7
1590.   57.01   1.67
1820.   55.42   1.6
2049.   59.35   1.5
2308.   58.32   1.56
2596.   57.28   1.6
2711.   57.13   1.368
2826.   55.61   1.33
2883.   54.79   1.315
2940.   53.78   1.325
3001.   54.41   1.3
3117.   55.93   1.2495
3291.   57.15   1.28
3377.   58.05   1.25
3522.   58.41   1.31
3725.   57.61   1.31
3899.   53.55   1.195
4015.   51.22   1.178
4188.   50.89   1.185"""
data = np.array([line.split() for line in data.strip().split('\n')], dtype='f8')
x, y, z = data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2]

def obj(a):
    z_hat = a[0]*y**a[1]*x**a[2]+a[3]*x**a[4]
    return ((z-z_hat)**2).sum()

import scipy.optimize as opt
print opt.minimize(obj, np.ones(5))
```

Or modify to use your solver. However, the function is quite scary and has lots of parameters.

Comment: So I don't need to declare `data` as `double` array first while using rectangular brackets `[[],[],...]'? Thank you very much. These basics are very useful for me to understand Python's grammar

Comment: You basically split the string by lines and split every line by whitespace. You get a list of lists which you then translate to 2 dimensional array. You take x, y, z as columns of that array and define you objective function.

Comment: Very smart. It seems there missed a statement of `import numpy as np` right before the converting from string to double array statement.

Comment: Correct. I forgot to copy that.